# Reading emails with groovy (Java Mail)

Tags: groovy, jakarta-mail

I am using groovy in order to access gmail and read the Inbox. It is regular JavaMail and will not describe it here.

So for simplicity, after I connect to the store, I use this:

```
folder.open(Folder.READ_ONLY)

 folder.messages.each { msg ->
    ...
    doSomething with msg
...
}
```

this is working fine.

However I have a performance issue. Sometimes messages[] could be big. Some folders contain more than 1000 messages, and checking them all takes time.

I am looking for a quicker way to get only those emails that are the most recent (for example messages from the last 5 days or something like that)

of course I have the date information in each msg and I could do my comparison, but this is not efficient since it will loop through the entire collection.

Is there a better way to get those messages?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have JavaMail issue a `SEARCH` command with the criterion `SINCE 04-JAN-2011`, you'll get back the set messages in the currently-selected folder delivered since January 4th.  (`SENTSINCE 04-JAN-2011` will do the same thing, only based on the "Date" message header.)

Something along the lines of this:

```
folder.search(new ReceivedDateTerm(ComparisonTerm.GE, sinceDate));
```

Comment: it worked, thanks a lot, I didn't know this function. There is a noticeable increase in speed, even though I didn't measure it, but it is obvious. Thanks again :-)